# Android - Access class property from an interface method

Tags: android, interface

I'm working on Android app with Java code.

I have a Fragment class with an array

```
List<String> lessonsWatched;
```

This Fragment calls an Activity. The activity has a close button which uses an interface

```
public interface LessonCheckmarkUpdate {
    void refreshCheckmarks(String id);
}
```

The initial Fragment includes the following method:

```
@Override
public void refreshCheckmarks(String id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "refreshCheckmarks: lessonsWatched: " + lessonsWatched);
}
```

The value I get for lessonsWatched is null even though it has a value.

How can I access the value in lessonsWatched from inside the interface method?

Comment: "This Fragment calls an Activity" -- what does this mean? "The value I get for lessonsWatched is null even though it has a value" -- my guess is that you have two (or more) fragment objects that implement that interface, and you are calling `refreshCheckmarks()` on the wrong one. That is just a guess, as your [mcve] is somewhat limited.

Comment: It means the fragment has a button and when I click it it loads an activity. The refreshCheckmarks method is being called since the Log method is executing. The problem is that the List appears as null.

Comment: "when I click it it loads an activity" -- what does that mean? Do you mean that you are calling `startActivity()`? If so, and if *that* activity is calling `refreshCheckmarks()` on some fragment, that is a different fragment than the fragment from your initial activity.

Comment: something not very clear here, you should post more code please :)